# problem with authenticated users

Tags: views, blocks, users

I'm on drupal 8.3, I have do the same for the view block and it's ok just for the admin user, but for authenticated users, the block does not appear, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> admin/people/permissions

and check if u have permissions for authenticated user.

Do you using the field permissions module?

Answer (score 0):

it's solved, i have to check view user information on admin/people/permissions for authenticated users